# Fixed Items in a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I need to create a TreeView in WPF that looks something like this:

- Admins *(Group)*

  - **Users** *(Fixed Node)*

    - Alice Adams *(User)*
    - Bob Brown *(User)*
  - **Permissions** *(Fixed Node)*

    - Delete *(Permission)*
    - Update *(Permission)*
- Guests *(Group)*

  - **Users** *(Fixed Node)*

    - Charlie Clarke *(User)*
  - **Permissions** *(Fixed Node)*

    - View *(Permission)*

I have a list of Groups, and each group has 3 properties:

- Name (string)
- Users (List)
- Permissions (List)

Displaying just the Users or Permissions is easy:

```
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

But I need to add 2 nodes (Users and Permissions) which expand to display the 2 list.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a MultiBinding with a converter to do something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupClass}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter-that-returns-lists-as-is}">
                <Binding Path="Users"/>
                <Binding Path="Permissions"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="IEnumerable[UserClass]" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
        <TextBlock Text="Users"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserClass}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="IEnumerable[PermissionClass]" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
        <TextBlock Text="Permissions"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PermissionClass}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The converter would just give back the lists unmodified as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I didn't use a converter, but exposed another property on my ViewModel that was an IEnumerable of Containers for Permissions and Users, but your answer got me going in the right direction - thank you!

Comment: @Darren - are you able to share your solution?

Comment: @Darren I realize this is a 2+ year old question, but if you can provide the solution you used for this issue, it may be beneficial.  I have a similar issue as yours and I am very curious what you did